# RN4020 Read advertising mensage

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I´m trying to read an advertisement message with the RN4020, the advertisement message is sent by other device (BlueMaestro sensor). Using my android phone, I can see the advertising raw data, but not with the RN4020.

I tried with this:

```
Echo On
SS,00000000
AOK
SR,80000000
AOK
R,1
Reboot
CMD
Echo On
J,1
AOK
F
AOK
DA9E45BEEA4F,1,DA9E45BE,,-49
```

I can only see the Mac address and the name of the device, i don't know why it doesn't display the advertisement message.

What may be the differences between the phone configuration and RN4020?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is really special to the modul. Maybe ask the guys from microchip with a ticket from www.microchip.com. They are really helpful an fast.

Answer (score 0):

For RN4020 you need to inform Advertisement mode

of it you can use SR(Set Feature) in autoadvertisement mode

80000000(central mode)+20000000(auto adversitement) = A00000000

So try it

```
...
SR,A00000000
AOK
...
```

or

```
...
SR,80000000
AOK
r,1
Reboot
CMD
A
AOK
...
```

"The “A” command is used to start advertisement.  When the device acts in a 
broadcaster role, which is enabled by the “N” command, the advertisement is an 
undirected, unconnectable, manufacturer-specific broadcast message. "

In central mode you, almost all, want to see another devices so no make sense you show advertisement, you want to find another one like the "DA9E45BEEA4F,1,DA9E45BE,,-49 " maybe you need to reorganize your question

If you need more information about it try to read features and commands in Microchip User Guide

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005191B.pdf

Or send another question

Regards, Guilherme